# transform a big dataframe with many None values to smaller one with indication of non null columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe with 4 columns with often 3 null values at every row. Sometimes there are 2 or 1 or even 0 null values but often 3.
I want to transform it to a two columns dataframe having in each row the non null value and the name of the column from which it was extracted.
Example: How to transform this dataframe

```
    df
Out[1]: 
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  3.0  2.0
3  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

to this One:

```
resultDF
Out[2]: 
   value columnName
0      1          a
1      2          b
2      3          c
3      2          d
4      1          c
```

The goal is to do it without looping on rows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for adjusting the `dataframe` :

```
import pandas as pd

# reading the csv 
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = df.melt(value_vars=['a','b','c','d'], var_name='foo', value_name='foo_value')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output :

```
  foo  foo_value
0   a        1.0
1   b        2.0
2   c        3.0
3   c        1.0
4   d        2.0
```